# The term 'Add-migration' is not recognized - VS2017 and EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-migrations

I am posting this question just in case the solution I found would help someone else out. While working in `Visual Studio 2017 rc4` each time I tried to run the `Add-Migration` command in the Package Manager console I get the following error:

> The term 'Add-migration' is not recognized...

Answer (score 64):

The solution that worked for me after trying a whole raft of other solutions posted, was to:

- right click on my project
- select `Manage Nuget Packages`
- select the browse tab
- thick `Include prerelease` check box
- install the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`

N.b that aspnetcore project in visual studio 2017 do not seem to have the `project.json` file.

Comment: For those wondering how the packages work. `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` is used for the package manager console i.e. `Add-Migration` `Update-Database`. `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet` is for the command line. `dotnet ef migrations add`. `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` belongs as a `PackageReference` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` as a `DotNetCliToolReference`.

Answer (score 37):

You just need to initialize the powershell module. I believe this is a bug, but it's pretty easy to work around. All you need to do is find the init.ps1 file and dot source it.

Just type this into the package manager console:

> C:\Users\YourUserAccount\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools\1.1.0-preview4-final\tools\init.ps1

Now the version might be different for you, depending on which one you have installed. Make sure you dot source the same version that is in your project.

Comment: Thank you! I started getting this error out of the blue. Reinstalling the nuget packages did not solve it. Very frustrating. This fixed it.

Comment: The same here. In fact, for me, it has broke the second time, and the second time I've came here and have found help, thanks!

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. This is the only solution that helped. I have added all the required dependencies and clitools references and it still wasn't working although dotnet ef command was but it was still not working until I ran this command.

Comment: it's kind of a joke. I have been always facing this issue before. install package is the solution for every project? I guess no.

Answer (score 18):

**Hi There**

This is almost an normal problem in Microsoft, and they pointing out the same solution:

[Microsoft Docs - Getting Started with EF Core on ASP.NET Core with a New database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db#create-the-database)

For me above dosn't solve my problem, but this line first does:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
PM> add-migration InitialCreate
```

/Cheers, Jan

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` package is installed. If it's not, then add it from NuGet or simply type the following in the Package Manager Console:

```sh
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

Installing the above package worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

If your are using VS 2019 and Dot.net core version 3.1

Just install the :  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools       from Manage NuGet Packages

this solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me.

1. Close all VIsual Studio instances.
2. Open VS.
3. Open Package Manager console, let it be initialized.
4. Now open the project and try Add-Migration.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem with a project created with VS2017 version 15.9.4 and .Net Core 2.1.

I have fixed it by adding **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools** to dependences of my project.

1. On *project* select **Manage Nuget Packages**
2. Browse and Search **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools**
3. Install it on your project

Then you can open **Package Manager Console** and use commands :
Add-Migration
Drop-Database
Get-DbContext
Scaffold-DbContext
Script-Migrations
Update-Database

Regards
dcube

Comment: Can you explain in further detail the steps necessary to implement this solution? This answer is so brief that it is at risk of being flagged for removal. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest .net Core 2.0 from the link below and it will fix your issue:
https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowscmd

Comment: Sounds too simple, but this fixed it for me too. I had started a project at home where I have .Net core 2.2 installed and got this error when I opened that project at the office and tried to do Add-Migration here. Installed .Net Core 2.2, restarted VS and all is well with the world.

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools and issue got fixed for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to copy the folder `microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools` from

`C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder`

To

`C:\Users\<user>\.nuget\packages`

Comment: Thank you for sharing - this is exactly what worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this to your CSPROJ file. This will most likely be fixed when the Core 2.0 is released. This stems from an issue where you can not install this package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet using the NUGET tools due to version requirements.

Then using CMD/PowerTools in the project directory you can issue the following commands:

dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate

dotnet ef database update

```
<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue with **VS2019 Enterprise** on a **.NET MVC 5** project with **EF6.3.0**. I was pulling my hair out and crushed for time. I was trying everything. In desperation, here's what I did that finally worked, FWIW.

1. Open VS2019
2. Let it completely finish all background processes on load (lower
   left-hand corner animated icon)
3. Close Package Manager Console
4. Right-click Project, select "Manage NuGet Packages"
5. Check "Include Pre-Release"
6. Choose "Browse" Tab Update EntityFramework to V6.4.0-preview2-19525-03
7. Close VS2019 Open VS2019 Select from Menu:
   Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Package Manager Console which opens
   the PM console
8. At THIS point, FINALLY, `add-migration "MyReferencePoint"` worked!

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

we get the same error when "add-migration", i try one solution which is update Package Manager by using follow step

1. In Visual Studio, from the "Tools" menu choose the "Extensions and Updates" option.
2. From the dialog that appears, expand the "Updates" node from the tree at the left side.
3. Select the "Visual Studio Gallery" option from the tree.
4. Finally, look for the Package Manager update in the list of updates at the right side of the dialog and click the "Update" button beside it.

it is approx 5 - 10 MB update, after update complete try Get-Help Add-Migration