# Visual Studio Update 2 - The term 'add-migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet for class library

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.1

I have a project I have written in ASP.NET core since the beta days. Always upgraded to later version and was able to run migrations with  migrations command package manager consoler.

However latest Visual Studio 2017 Update 2 migrations commands in package console are no longer recognized.

If I run the command in Package Manager Console

```
add-migration
```

I get

> The term 'add-migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

I upgraded from Visual Studio 2017 Update 1 and one of my packages in my class library csproj `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` seem to have been upgraded from 1.1.0 to 1.1.1 which seems to have caused migration commands to not be recognized. To try resolve this I changed Tools back to 1.1.0 back but still the migrations powershell commmands don't work.
I am using the powershell commands and not the dotnet ef commands which aren't supported in a class library.

I tried 
- adding/removing packages `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet` and  to my csproj and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` reopening closing Visual Studio in between.
- running dotnet restore
- running the correspondingcsproj  version nuget ef toold init.ps1 in package manager console
 I have tried all the stackoverflow answers. Nothing works

Comment: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5456

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The term 'Add-migration' is not recognized - VS2017 and EntityFrameworkCore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42390942/the-term-add-migration-is-not-recognized-vs2017-and-entityframeworkcore)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by

- Close all instances of Visual Studio 2017
- deleting all folders called microsoft.entityFrameworkcore in C:\Users\myuser.nuget\packages\
- Open my visual studio project.
- Run `dotnet restore` on all my projects
- Run `add-migration` command in package manager console with my class library the Default project and it gets recognized

Comment: Update: disabling all extensions and restarting VS got PMC working again.  I then re-enabled all extensions and restarted again.. and PMC is working fine for me again.