# Net Core 2.1 install Entity Framework Core does not work?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I create a new project using VS2017, select new Console App (Core) version 2.1; etc. When I use NuGet to install the Entity Framewwork Core, version 2.1.1, it is not installing to the Assemblies directory but instead appears under the NuGet directory. When I try to add a migration using the package manager I get a 'The term 'add-migration' is not recognized' error. I have reviewed the other SO answers to this problem, and searched google, but none of those helped.

I have another project, it's an older one from several months ago, where the Entity Framework Core was installed under the Assemblies directory and for that project everything seems to work.

From the above it appears that where NuGet places the Entity Framework Core dll is the only difference and it is causing the package manager to fail to find it.

The get-module command for the older project shows the Entity Framework Core and the correct version, but get-module for the new project does not.

Any thoughts on why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Could this be [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42390942/the-term-add-migration-is-not-recognized-vs2017-and-entityframeworkcore) you are looking for? Note that there is more than 1 answer/solution.

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed that solution, but adding the tools worked.

Comment: Officially, for people stumbling on this post, your solution was to add the NuGet Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools ? If so then cool! You can mark as solution ^^!

Comment: Yes, everything about where the DLL's were installed was a red herring, probably not relevant to the problem. Installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools solved the problem and I can now add-migrations, update-database without any issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The term 'Add-migration' is not recognized - VS2017 and EntityFrameworkCore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42390942/the-term-add-migration-is-not-recognized-vs2017-and-entityframeworkcore)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42390942/the-term-add-migration-is-not-recognized-vs2017-and-entityframeworkcore) :

*The solution that worked for me after trying a whole raft of other solutions posted, was to right click on my project => select 'Manage Nuget Packages' => select the browse tab, but thick 'Include prerelease' check box, and install the 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools'. N.b that aspnetcore project in visual studio 2017 do not seem to have the 'project.json' file.*